# How to find the rank/nullity of this map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I know the nullity must be 4 since the dimension of the kernel is 4. However, I'm stuck on how to find the rank. Am I correct in thinking it would be 1, since the vectors are not linearly independent?
[image: This is the problem]

Comment: [Rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: @Eminem thank you, but I'm still confused on how to find the rank even with the theorem :/ the dimension is 3, and I believe the nullity of the kernel is 4 but I'm not entirely sure?

Comment: In the theorem i've provided, what are $V$ and $W$ in your case?

Comment: @Eminem V is the 5x1 matrix (x,y,z,w,r) and W is the 5x1 matrix to the right of it in the image

Comment: @Eminem I see, so the dimension would actually be 5! But I'm still unsure if I'm correct in thinking that the rank would be 1?

Comment: Not so accurate. $V=\mathbb{R}^5$, so $dim(V)=?$

Comment: @Eminem wouldn't the dimension of V be 5?

Comment: @Eminem I just read my textbook and it has a proof for the dimension of R5 being 5. I'm sorry if I'm getting confused, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @strugglingincs123 The dimension is indeed correct. The part that I suspect Eminem was objecting to is that you called $V$ "the $5 \times 1$ matrix" rather than "the set (or space) of $5 \times 1$ matrices".

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh okay, got it thanks! Do you know how I can confirm that the nullity is 4?

Comment: @BenGrossmann And, is it sensible to know that since the vectors aren't linearly independent the rank must be one?